# How to append all the input(a string) from user in a list without overwriting the last string

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
l=["hello","hie","yes","sun be","listen"]
k=input("type to chat: ")
l.append(k)
print(l)
```

I am trying to append each new element(from user) in the list but every time i run this script only the last element(string) is appended and printed overwriting the previous one.How to add each and every element in the list.[Output screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56OJP.png)

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean. it out puts ["hello","hie","yes","sun be","listen","the line i just wrote"]

Comment: Every time you run your program, it's a totally blank slate. All memory of previous input is not saved into a database. Do you intend to preserve program state across multiple executions (use a database), or are you attempting to enter multiple entries in one execution (use a loop)?

Comment: At the start of the script you set the list to `["hello","hie","yes","sun be","listen"]`, then you append a single item to it. You will get the same list with a single additional entry *every time you run the script*. Why would you expect anything else to happen? Even if the list `l` did somehow magically persist between execution runs, is is reset each time by that first line.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("text.txt","r") as f:
    filo = f.readline()
    l = filo.split(",")
    k = input("type to chat: ")
    fila = open("text.txt", "w")
    fila.write(filo+","+k)
    fila.close()
    print(l+[k])
```

is this what you wanted?

Comment: Exactly this is what I was trying but with a list, is it possible to do the same with a list. How to separate every entry with a comma.

Comment: they are now seperated by a comma instead of a space, and it have always used a list. It's caled l = filo.split(",")